# Newly created app service not available as deployment option in Devops Release

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I've had a working ADO build and release pipeline for about a year now, recently I had to recreate the App Service because it was originally created in the wrong region.
I deleted the original, then recreated it with the same name in the proper region and after this my existing release pipeline predictably failed.

So I went to edit the ADO release and in the "App Service Name" in the "Azure App Service deploy" task, the new app service is not listed (plenty of others are still listed, just not this new one).
Checked permissions, refreshed pages, logged out and logged back in, logged in as a user that's an administrator for both the ADO and the Portal. Nothing I have tried is working.

Answer (score 2):

7 hours after it was created, it just showed up in the list of avaialable services to deploy to...

Comment: For me it took 30 minutes or so and then it showed up